# From where Ubuntu One Music Store gets its musics?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I wish to know, where the Ubuntu One Music Store musics come from? It is from Amazon? If it is, why there is some musics available in Amazon that is unavailable in Ubuntu One Music Store? How can I get them? Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvote? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The music from the Ubuntu One Music Store is delivered by [7digital](http://www.7digital.com)

Comment: And if an album that I want to buy isn't there? For example, search for Bebo Norman on your Dash, it returns 9 albums. I want his first album, "Fabric of Verse", that is not in 7digital. There is a way to get it on Ubuntu One Music Store?

Comment: Hi Twinsen, sorry for the late reply!
And sorry, I don't know how you could do that, if it's not available on 7digital.